# Login error with iOS Swift: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, nsmutabledata

i need your help cause i cant use this piece of code. 
I was using it in obj-c and now i want to use it with iOS swift, but when i simulate it, there is an error when using webData cause it's nil, but i don't know how to fix it cause its the same that i've been using for a long time with obj-c.

Well, this is my code:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!){
    NSLog("webData:\(webData)")
    webData.length = 0
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
    webData.appendData(data)
}
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: NSError!){
    NSLog("ERROR with theConenction")
}
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace protectionSpace: NSURLProtectionSpace!) -> Bool{
    return true
}
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge!){
    if challenge.previousFailureCount >= 3{
        textResult = "this connection requires user & password"
        connection.cancel()
    } else {
        NSLog("didRecieveAuthentication")
        var credential:NSURLCredential = NSURLCredential.credentialWithUser(txt_user.text, password: txt_pass.text, persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.ForSession)
        challenge.sender.useCredential(credential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
        NSLog("Credential: \(credential)")
    }
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!){
    NSLog("DONE. Recieved Bytes: \(webData.length)")

    NSLog("webData\n\(webData)")

    var convertToStringData: NSString = NSString(data: webData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    textResult = convertToStringData
    NSLog("textResult:\n\(textResult)")
}


func validateUserCredentials(){
    var txtURL: NSString = "http://ws.itteria.cat/leina.nsf"
    var nodeContent:NSMutableString
    var locationOfWebService: NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString(txtURL)
    NSLog("web url = \(locationOfWebService)")
    var theRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: locationOfWebService)

    theRequest.addValue("text/html", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    theRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    var connect: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection.connectionWithRequest(theRequest, delegate: self)!


}
```

I'm calling to func ValidateCredentials and then i get this error when using webData:

```
webData nil
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

webData is declared here:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, NSURLSessionDelegate{

let webData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData(bytes: nil, length: 0)
```

Hope you can help me, cause i don't know what else can i do :S

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That means that `webData` has been assigned a `nil` value.
Since you declared it as a implicitly unwrapped optional `var webData: NSMutableData!`, you expect that it will always be assigned a non-nil value.

The solution is to make it an optional `var webData: NSMutableData?`, and check after the assignment whether it contains a value or nil - most likey using an optional binding.

Suggested reading: [Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_491)

Comment: If i use `var webData: NSMutableData?`then i cant use `webData.length = 0` or `webData.appendData(data)` -- 'NSMutableData?' does not have a member named 'length'.

Comment: Use optional binding (see linked documentation): `if let webData = webData { ... }`. Add your code inside

Comment: this doesnt fix the problem, but i've fixed using this :)
`let webData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData(bytes: nil, length: 0)`
Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Hmm... that makes me think something is broken in your logic. Can you post in your question the code where webData is declared, initialized and assigned?